# Outlook add-in: makeEwsRequestAsync error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized"

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook add-in. My add-in sends some requests to Exchange via [makeEwsRequestAsync(data, callback, [userContext])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/Office.context.mailbox#makeewsrequestasyncdata-callback-usercontext). It works well except for one customer. `makeEwsRequestAsync` returns following error:

```
{ 
  name: 'GenericResponseError',
  message: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.',
  code: 9020 
}
```

[image]

I found this request in browser's dev tools. This is `https://mail.my-company.com/owa/service.svc?action=ExecuteEwsProxy&ID=-48&AC=1`. Status code of this request is 200 but response says about error:

```
{
"Body":null,
"ErrorMessage":"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.",
"StatusCode":0,
"StatusDescription":null,
"WasProxySuccessful":false
}
```

1. It works for other customers, so this isn't the issue with the *ReadWriteMailbox* permission
2. We checked the `OAuthAuthentication` and this is "true" for all their Exchanges servers.
3. The customer has a cluster of Exchange servers with Exchange 2016 CU 12 v15.1.1713.5 and Exchange 2013 CU 22 v15.0.1473.3
4. I have a sandbox with Exchange 2016 CU 12 v15.1.1713.5 and it works well. And in response `WasProxySuccessful` is `true`
5. The issue is reproducible in web Outlook and in desktop Outlook in Windows version 16.0.4738.0000.

An example of request which I use in `makeEwsRequestAsync`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
      </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
        <GetItem
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
          xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
          <ItemShape>
            <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
          </ItemShape>
          <ItemIds>
            <t:ItemId Id="${id}" />
          </ItemIds>
        </GetItem>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>;
```

Where is the problem ? Is it possible that the issue is related with this the combination of Exchange 2016 + Exchange 2013 ? What else can I check ?

Comment: May want to first narrow it down to where the response is coming back from.  You can check the response headers on this 401 to see if only mentions the front-end server, or also mentions the back-end server, if the latter it means it is passing authentication on the front-end but then being rejected at the back-end.  Are there additional response headers that may indicate an error condition?

Comment: @brian-clink Maybe I didn't understand properly your comment but in `makeEwsRequestAsync` I didn't get usual HTTP response. I've got `Office.AsyncResult` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.asyncresult?view=word-js-preview. I don't see any other information about the issue here.

Comment: I added a screenshot with the full response of `makeEwsRequestAsync` in the question.

Comment: Check the response headers in built-in browser F12 debugging tools or Fiddler.  It is clearly 401 access denied, but the request/response headers could give more clues.  Check if there is any differences in how the EWS virtual directory is configured on the Exchange Servers related to authentication, and may need to trace where the request went and which server rejected it, which may not be obvious because the request may have been proxied from a "front-end" CAS server to a "back-end" MBX server (generally the server where the mailbox is active) or simply rejected from the front-end.

Comment: Checked network requests of Office.js lib (added this information above). The request which returns the error is `owa/service.svc?action=ExecuteEwsProxy`. Status code is `200`. But response body contains error message. I don't see any critical differences comparing with successful requests in my sandbox. 
Unfortunately the customer still didn't provide information about tracing this issue in server side :(

Comment: I would check the response headers anyway, but as it is a 200 response, I'm not expecting you will see anything.  The "WasProxySuccessful": false is leading me to think that it had a failure proxying the request to the EWS back-end where the mailbox is active.  I would try to find the corresponding request to the back-end - I think it still looks like /owa/service.svc going to the back-end, and then it makes its own local native request to EWS which should also show up in the IIS back-end logs.  Review the back-end IIS EWS vdir config.  Microsoft might have better / more effective suggestions.